# NullInjectorError: No provider for FirebaseX in Ionic 4 FirebaseX

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working with FirebaseX in an Ionic 4 project and i get this error.

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for FirebaseX
```

How do I load this service in the appModule.ts?
If i just put FirebaseX in the provider section i get this error

```
Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule'
```

Please help.

FirebaseX - https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex

Thanks.

Comment: Have you run the command `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex`  in your project?

Comment: yes I did, but still can't inject it through a constructor

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way as `StatusBar` and `SplashScreen`, on `app.module` import module and declare it as provider:

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { FirebaseX } from '@ionic-native/firebase-x/ngx';

@NgModule({
...
  providers: [
    InAppBrowser,
    SplashScreen,
    StatusBar,
    FirebaseX,
  ],
...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add it in `provider` array in `NgModule`. You can use it directly:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
npm install @ionic-native/firebase-x

import { FirebaseX } from "@ionic-native/firebase-x/ngx";
constructor(private firebase: FirebaseX)

this.firebase.getToken().then(token => console.log(`The token is ${token}`))
this.firebase.onMessageReceived().subscribe(data => console.log(`FCM message: ${data}`));
```

The [cordova-plugin-firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex) is a fork of [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase)

Comment: But if I don't put it in the array I get this error - AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FcmService -> FirebaseX]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FcmService -> FirebaseX]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for FirebaseX!

Comment: `import { FirebaseX } from "@ionic-native/firebase-x/ngx";`, `providers: [
    ...
    FirebaseX
  ]` you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have import it correctly? For Ionic 4 you have to import the "ngx" folder. So adding it to the Provider Section is correct and necessary.

But the Import have to look like :
import { FirebaseX } from "@ionic-native/firebase-x/ngx";